# Recommendations to manage updates in network following update-manager rules

Tags: networking, updates, update-manager

I have ~50 workstations that I want to update their installed software with every possible updated package inside release repository without upgrading distro (I don't want to go from 16.04 to 18.04 for example).

I can SSH into them but I don't know if apt update && sudo apt upgrade is safe because update-manager (which always worked for me) seems to show less software to upgrade and I don't want to change Ubuntu releases on those machines (some old hardware dropped support in newer kernels).

I also think it would be the best to do so without using lots of bandwidth from ubuntu apt mirrors.

I was thinking something like having local apt mirror (to avoid downloading the same files from external servers 50 times if aprox 300mb per machine justificates doing so).

Doing one small script in Python+Paramiko to iterate each machine and update or would it be best to learn Ansible? I'm not using domain joined workstations so I think if I would use Ansible to deploy I would need to specify each login/password and that seems much more work, and I don't really know Ansible.

TL;DR What do you recommend to deploy updates in Ubuntu 16.04 network environment without domain joined machines and without wasting others bandwidth? (I can connect to each machine using SSH)

Thank you!

Comment: Whole lot of possible issues in there. I'm not sure which question you want us to answer?

Comment: What would you do to update all softwares in 50 Ubuntu installed machines without updating distro version, if you wanted to be lazy and safe? Only you has the root password, different users

Comment: I would sit down at my terminal and run my ssh script that runs 50 apt update and 50 apt upgrade. I would bring a sandwich because I intend to read all 50 sets of output before hitting 'Y' each time. With occasional pondering, it should take about two hours. Then I would edit the script to enable Unattended-Upgrades, and set a specific time each day to run it so all the machines are updated identically. Finally I would look into a caching proxy for the bandwidth during future updates.